# Unity XML Serialization of complex class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to serialize a class with some `Dictionary<string, CustomStruct>`

inside? Seems that I need to implement myself a serializer because Unity report that is impossible to serialize Dictionary because of IDictionary implementation.

Part of my class is this:

```
public class Ship
{

    public struct Stat
    {
        public int StatValue { get; set; }
        public int StatLast { get; set; }

        public Stat(int statValue, int statLast)
        {
            StatValue = statValue;
            StatLast = statLast;
        }
    }

public int a = 0;
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Owner { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, Stat> Aim { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, Stat> Dodge { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, Stat> EmPower { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, Stat> HullPoint { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, Stat> CorePower { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, Stat> Reaction { get; set; }
public string Size { get; set; }
public int CurrentHullPoint { get; set; }
public int CurrentCorePower { get; set; }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `[Serializable]` and the `[SerializeField]` attributes.

```
[Serializable]
public class Ship
{

    public struct Stat
    {
        public int StatValue { get; set; }
        public int StatLast { get; set; }

        public Stat(int statValue, int statLast)
        {
            StatValue = statValue;
            StatLast = statLast;
        }
    }

public int a = 0;
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Owner { get; set; }
[SerializeField]
public Dictionary<string, Stat> Aim { get; set; }
[SerializeField]
public Dictionary<string, Stat> Dodge { get; set; }
[SerializeField]
public Dictionary<string, Stat> EmPower { get; set; }
[SerializeField]
public Dictionary<string, Stat> HullPoint { get; set; }
[SerializeField]
public Dictionary<string, Stat> CorePower { get; set; }
[SerializeField]
public Dictionary<string, Stat> Reaction { get; set; }
public string Size { get; set; }
public int CurrentHullPoint { get; set; }
public int CurrentCorePower { get; set; }
...
```

Not tested but that should work.

**EDIT**:

include `System.Runtime.Serialization`
Use `[DataContract]` and  `[DataMember]`. Initialize the Dictionary in Constructor with **no** **parameter**.

This works for standard C#. Don't know if it will work in Unity.

```
[DataContract]
public class Ship
{

    // Must use parameterless constructor for serialization
    public Ship()
    {
     Aim = new Dictionary<string, Stat>();
     Dodge = new Dictionary<string, Stat>();
     EmPower = new Dictionary<string, Stat>();
     HullPoint = new Dictionary<string, Stat>();
     CorePower = new Dictionary<string, Stat>();
     Reaction = new Dictionary<string, Stat>();
    }

    public struct Stat
    {
        public int StatValue { get; set; }
        public int StatLast { get; set; }

        public Stat(int statValue, int statLast)
        {
            StatValue = statValue;
            StatLast = statLast;
        }
    }

public int a = 0;
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Owner { get; set; }
 [DataMember]
public Dictionary<string, Stat> Aim { get; set; }
 [DataMember]
public Dictionary<string, Stat> Dodge { get; set; }
 [DataMember]
public Dictionary<string, Stat> EmPower { get; set; }
 [DataMember]
public Dictionary<string, Stat> HullPoint { get; set; }
 [DataMember]
public Dictionary<string, Stat> CorePower { get; set; }
 [DataMember]
public Dictionary<string, Stat> Reaction { get; set; }
public string Size { get; set; }
public int CurrentHullPoint { get; set; }
public int CurrentCorePower { get; set; }
...
```

Comment: Same error:
NotSupportedException: The type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[Test+Stat, Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] is not supported because it implements IDictionary.

Comment: Try the second method I provided in Edit. That may work for you.

Comment: Error still the same :(

Comment: Probably because you are using a custom type "Stat" from Dictionary<string, Stat>(). Would have worked if you had Dictionary<string, string>(). Not sure why it is not working. This is Unity and some standard stuff don't work. If I come up with another idea I will update this answer. Right now, I dont have another solution.

Comment: I ran the class you provided. It didn't show any error. It compiled. What Unity version are you using and what when do you see the error above?

Comment: the error is not during compiling but in runtime.
Exactly when the command `serializer.Serialize(stream, _test);` are launched.
Unity 5.3.1f1

Comment: I ran the code and no runtime error. I use Unity 5.4 B10 beta. Maybe that's why I am not getting any error. You can download it because Unity made it free for non pro users few days ago. http://unity3d.com/unity/beta

Comment: but you can obtain a file?
because the problem is when it write the file!

Comment: I did not obtain any file after runtime. How about this, upload the complete code. Remove things you consider to be confidential in your code and upload the full code of class Ship. The complete that is required to make that error show up.

Comment: you must add a serializer that write on file, but trying to find a solution I delete it. But is simple enough.
create a `FileStream stream = File.Create(<url_here>);` Than create a serializer `XmlSerializer writer = 
            new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Ship));` and than `write.Serialize(stream, _ship);` where `_ship` is an instance of Ship with filled properties

Comment: Update the code in your question with the code above.